# Elixir delete occurrences that happen more then once in list

Tags: elixir

I have a list like `["A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E"]` and I want to delete completely elements which occur more then once.

In this case the output would be `["B", "C", "E"]`

I've been looking at using `Enum.dedup`. So far the best I've come up with is N^2 algorithms which find the duplicates and then filter again.

What is the best idiomatic Elixir way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`O(n log n)` solution using a list comprehension with `Enum.frequencies/1`:

```
iex(1)> list = ["A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E"]
["A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E"]
iex(2)> for {k, v} <- Enum.frequencies(list), v == 1, do: k
["B", "C", "E"]
```

`Enum.frequencies/1` is `O(n log n)` since it creates a `Map` of the frequencies of each element and inserting one value into a `Map` is `O(log n)`. [Source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.14.1/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1318)

Note that this will not preserve the order of elements in the original list. For that, @sabiwara's answer is better.

---

Proposed improvement by @sabiwara in comments:

```
iex(3)> for {k, 1} <- Enum.frequencies(list), do: k
["B", "C", "E"]
```

In a `for` comprehension, if a pattern does not match an element, that element is skipped, which makes this a really elegant solution.

Comment: This one is nice, but it is worth mentioning it will lose the ordering, which might or not be an issue depending on the requirements. Even more compact using pattern-matching: `for {k, 1} <- Enum.frequencies(list), do: k` (just golfing ^^).

Comment: @sabiwara you're right about the ordering, I'll add a note. Matching on `{k, 1}` is really cool!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Enum.frequencies/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#frequencies/1) to build a map (`Enum.uniq/1` also does this under the hood, plus a pass to reverse the list) and then you can simply filter:

```elixir
counts = Enum.frequencies(list)
Enum.reject(list, &Map.fetch!(counts, &1) > 1)
```

Assuming the list is sorted (or at least that duplicated are always successive), you can do it in one pass and O(N) with recursion for instance:

```elixir
defmodule Dedup do
  def dedup([]), do: []
  def dedup([h, h | t]) do
    # removing all successive instances of h
    skipped = Enum.drop_while(t, & &1 === h)
    dedup(skipped)
  end
  
  def dedup([h | t]) do
    [h | dedup(t)]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> find the duplicates and then filter again

That's the answer. You can use [`--`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#--/2), which is O(n log n).

```elixir
dupes = list -- Enum.uniq(list)
Enum.reject(list, &(&1 in dupes))
```

Comment: `reject` will be O(n2) though if you are using `in` on a list.
You should probably convert dupes to a `MapSet` first: `dupes = MapSet.new(list -- Enum.uniq(list))`

Comment: You could also do `Enum.uniq` over the `dupes` too. However, both of those suggestions (and your answer) are slower in my benchmarks, and simplicity wins. It may be different for longer lists.

Comment: I think the question was how to avoid N^2 algorithms, but there might be a simpler algorithm here.